# C#: if a byte is 0 to 255, then how come Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("çõ") return values of up to 6 digits i.e. 195167 and 195181?

Tags: encoding, byte, gsm

This is my code:

```
byte[] sample = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("çõ");
foreach (byte c in sample)
  Debug.Write(c.ToString());
```

I am struggling with encoding messages for sending texts thru a GSM Modem using PDU mode.  The encoder algorithm expects bytes to be less than 127, and does not work for values 195167 and 195181 (for the Portuguese alphabets "çõ".  It works if only ASCII characters are present in the message.

Comment: Try  either `[System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncodeUnicode("çõ")` or `[System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("çõ"))` (above `.NET` examples in PowerShell are easy convertible to C#).

Answer (score 0):

Duh.  Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("çõ") actually returned 2 bytes each (called surrogate pairs).  First character returned 195 and 167 while the second character returned 195 and 181.  Discovered it when used Debug.WriteLine instead of just Debug.Write.  As a side note: some Portuguese alphabet (like ç and õ) are not in GSM character set.  GSM set only uses bytes 0-127 for characters.  You have to encode Portuguese messages into UCS2 character set.